# How to optimize Intializecomponent()?

Tags: c#, optimization, listbox, initialization, wpf-controls

I have a wpf window which has a ScrollViewer and a TextBlock. When the user opens this window, we fetch 1000 AT objects from server and add to that window in scrollviewer. When a particular item is clicked in scrollviewer its corresponding info is populated on textblock fields.
The scrollviewer is made of multiple Mylistboxentry instances.

The problem is that in the earlier version this operation of adding 1000 AT objects to WPF window used to take ~3-4 seconds, now it takes way too much time ~10 secs.

I digged further and this delay is comming from InitializeComponent() of constructor of

```cs
public myListBoxEntry(object details, string Text, string descriText, bool invalid, bool selected)
```

as the number of listboxentry objects to be added increases, the total delay also increases and intializecomponent() takes 7-8 ms for each instance.

How to optimize this?
What could be reason it worked faster in the older version?

I cannot try multi-threading as this is adding component to the UI operation and main thread only can do this.

Answer (score 1):

A typical solution would be to use "virtualization", this only creates the expensive WPF objects when actually needed. Since you most likely will not see all 1000 items at a time this can be a major performance benefit.

You likely would need to rewrite your control a bit to make use of this. ListView/ListBox should have virtualization enabled by default. If you are doing something custom you may need to derive from ItemsControl and use a  VirtualizingStackPanel with virtualization set to true as the ItemsPanel.

Read more at [Optimizing performance: Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)